# How to style tabs Angular Material?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have Material Tabs:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <md-tab-group [selectedIndex]="0">
    <md-tab label="Sd">
      kkk
    </md-tab>

</div>
</div>
```

I tried to style each tab, but it does not work:

```
#tabs .mat-tab-label {
  width: 167px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `material's` `min-width` is set to `160px`, so you will have to reset that and then set your own `width`. Below is the default property set.

```
.mat-tab-label[_ngcontent-c19] {
    line-height: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: .6;
    min-width: 160px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

So try something like this

```
#tabs .mat-tab-label {
 min-width : 0px; // added
  width: 167px;
  height: 42px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

**Working example** : [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oyzPvdpsnouO9MIkhS74?p=preview)

Comment: Whats does mean default?

Comment: I need to get width depends of width text inside.

Comment: open `material` docs, and inspect the `tabs` .You will see what all properties are set

Comment: try resetting `min-width` property